# Download files Angular, .Net 5

Tags: c#, angular, zip

I have a problem downloading files.
When I download the file, it turns out to be empty, I think that the problem is in the wrong headers, but I could not figure out what exactly.

I have a response body
[from controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy8mU.png)

But I have empty response arraybuffer
[from component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84HKM.png)

And empty zip downloaded

What am I doing wrong?

**request.component.ts**

```
downloadZip() {
  this.requestService.downloadZip(this.request.id)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      const blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/zip' });
      saveAs(blob, 'Обращение №' + this.request.id + '.zip');
    })
}
```

**request.service.ts**

```
downloadZip(requestId: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/request/downloadZip?id=' + requestId, { responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
}
```

**RequestController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/request/downloadZip")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadZip(int id)
{
    var stream = await _fileStoreService.GetRequestFilesZip(id);

    Response.Body = stream;
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

    return Ok();
}
```

**FileStoreService.cs**

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> GetRequestFilesZip(int id)
{
    var query = await _db.RequestMedia
        .Where(_ => _.RequestId == id)
        .ToListAsync();

    var fileSharePath = Path.Combine(_configuration["FileTableRootPath"], "RequestFileStore");

    var files = new List<string>();
    foreach (var media in query)
        files.Add(Path.Combine(fileSharePath, media.Hash + Path.GetExtension(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(media.Name))));

    var memory = new MemoryStream();
    ZipStrings.UseUnicode = true;
    using(var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(memory))
    {
        zipStream.SetLevel(3);

        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            var entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file))
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now
            };

            zipStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

            var inStream = new MemoryStream();
            using var f = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            await f.CopyToAsync(inStream);

            inStream.Close();

            var content = inStream.ToArray();
            await zipStream.WriteAsync(content.AsMemory(0, content.Length));
            zipStream.CloseEntry();
        }

        zipStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
    }

    memory.Position = 0;

    return memory;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this

**request.service.ts**

```
downloadZip(requestId: number) {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/request/downloadZip?id=' + requestId, { responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

and this

**RequestController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/request/downloadZip")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadZip(int id)
{
    var stream = await _fileStoreService.GetRequestFilesZip(id);

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/zip");
}
```

Everything works fine